# Follow local file link in vim with Markdown syntax

Tags: vim, markdown, neovim

When editing markdown files in (neo)vim, I'd like to be able to quickly jump to links pointing to local files. Something like `gf` or `gx`. However, `gx` kinda works, but opens the local file in a **different** (i.e. not vim) editor -- `gf` only works when i click on the actual filename:

```markdown
[test][1]

[1]: some_file.md
```

I.e., I literally have to `gf` on `some_file.md` but I'd like to be able to do the same one `test` and `1` as well.

I'm using vanilla (neo)vim without any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ge` with cursor over the link, as shown in [mappings](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#mappings).

You can configure how you wanna open the file in vim defining the variable `g:vim_markdown_edit_url_in` to one of values:

- `tab` - to open in new tab
- `vsplit` - to open in a vertical screen split
- `hsplit` - to open in a horizontal screen split
- `current` - to open in current buffer

Example:

```
let g:vim_markdown_edit_url_in = 'tab'
```

More info in "[How to open new Files](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#change-how-to-open-new-files)"

Comment: I probably should have been more clear, I'm using vim without any plugins.